# What is the best way to populate an iWork pages doc in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openxml, iwork

I have a document layout that I want populated with data from my rails app and outputted to the client as a pages document. Is there an easy / good way to do this? Is there a way to do this with both Microsoft word and Apple pages?

thx

proposed simple layout:

```
Category:
  Sub-Category
     Item   price 
     Item   price

  Sub-Category
     Item      price
```

Comment: Export as CSV and import? How much do you want to do by API and how much manually?

Comment: added a proposed simple layout above - would like this to be generated on server obviously